# Template function "is_same" with pointer this, unexpected behaviour?

Tags: c++, types, c++11, g++

Related question: [template-function-is-same-in-template-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843222/template-function-is-same-in-template-classes)

I'm a bit disconcerted with the type of the pointer "this" (gcc 4.7.2, c++11). In principle, the type of pointer "this" of a non-const object of type C, for example, is "C * const", and thus, the type of "*this" is "C". But the behaviour of the "is_same" class confused me.

Test:

```
// this-type.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class C
{
public:
   void test()
   {
       cout << boolalpha;

       cout << "'this' const?" << "              "
            << is_const<decltype(this)>::value << endl;

       cout << "'*this' const?" << "             "
            << is_const<decltype(*this)>::value << endl;

       cout << "'*this' and 'C' the same?" << "  "
            << is_same<decltype(*this), C>::value << endl;

       cout << "'this' and 'C*' the same?" << "  "
            << is_same<decltype(this), C*>::value << endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
    C c;

    c.test();
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ --version | grep g++
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
$ g++ -std=c++11 this-type.cpp
$ ./a.out
'this' const?              false
'*this' const?             false
'*this' and 'C' the same?  false
'this' and 'C*' the same?  true
```

However, the expected output is:

```
$./a.out
'this' const?              true   // C* const
'*this' const?             false  // C
'*this' and 'C' the same?  true
'this' and 'C*' the same?  false  // C* const vs. C*
```

What are happened here?

Comment: How did `g++ --version | grep gcc` produce a string without `gcc` in it?

Comment: Haha, you're right. Corrected.

Comment: the expected output is not 'this' and 'C*' aren’t the same : they are.

Comment: this is C * const, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the type of `this` is `C *`

> 9.3.2 The this pointer [class.this]
>
> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword this is a prvalue
>   expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called.
>   The type of this in a member function of a class X is X*.
>
> ...

No mention for `X *const`, etc. The `this` pointer is a *prvalue*, that's why it cannot be assigned to, not because it const-qualified.

PS. By the way, it seems

```
C *p; // for any type C
is_same<declype (*p), C &>::value == true
```

though it may be an artefact of the implementation (compiler or `is_same`), because the standard says:

> 5.3.1 Unary operators [expr.unary.op]
>
> 1 ...
>
> ... If the type of the expression is “pointer to T,” the type of the result is “T.” ...

Comment: `decltype` on an unparenthesized lvalue gives the corresponding reference type.  7.1.6.2p4.

Answer (score 3):

> #### 9.3.2 The this pointer [class.this]
>
> 1 - [...] the keyword `this` is a prvalue expression whose value
>   is the address of the object for which the function is called. The type of `this` in a member function of a class `X` is `X*`.

`this` is not a `const` lvalue, it's a prvalue expression, so it doesn't need to be `const`.  You can't assign to it because it's a prvalue, the same reason you can't write `2 + 2 = 5`.

Comment: At least with g++ 4.6.3, I can't do `X *&& xp = this`.  It complains `invalid initialization of reference of type ‘A*&&’ from expression of type ‘A* const'`.  May be a bug.

Comment: @VaughnCato gcc bug, I think; clang 3.0 compiles it fine.