# Template function is_same in template classes

Tags: c++, types, c++11, this

Why this code produces a false output?

```
//this-type.cpp  

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename testype>
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        cout << boolalpha;
        cout << is_same<decltype(*this), A<int>>::value << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A<int>
{
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 this-type.cpp
$ ./a.out
false
```

The type of "*this" inside A through B is A< int >, isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`*this` is an lvalue of type `A`, so `decltype(*this)` will give the reference type `A &`.  Recall that `decltype` on an lvalue gives the reference type:

```
    cout << is_same<decltype(*this), A<int>>::value << endl;
    cout << is_same<decltype(*this), A<int> &>::value << endl;
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

Comment: Then, the complete type of 'this' what is, 'A<int>&* this'?

Comment: Definitely not obvious though.

Comment: The last line doesn't work for me. My output is 'false', 'true', 'false' (g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2)

Comment: @Peregring-lk `this` is a prvalue expression of type `A<int> *`.  Indirecting `this` gives an lvalue expression of type `A<int>`.  The type of an expression isn't always the same as how `decltype` reports it.

Comment: @Peregring-lk oops, my mistake on the parenthesis bit.  Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
typedef std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type this_type;
cout << is_same<this_type, A<int>>::value << endl;
```

and maybe `remove_cv` in some other contexts (if you don't care about `const`/`volatile`) like this:

```
typedef std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type this_type;
typedef std::remove_cv<this_type>::type no_cv_this_type;
cout << is_same<no_cv_this_type, A<int>>::value << endl;
```

Comment: And make sure remove_cv is *after* remove_reference.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes remove_reference has colateral effects? Why is it neccesary to use remove_cv "after" remove_reference?

Comment: @Peregring-lk because the order matters. See here http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/05/29/type-traits-galore.html#bare_types

Comment: @Peregring-lk basically because a `int&const` doesn't exist, yet is distinct from a `int const&`.  `remove_cv` removes the const-volatile from the "outermost layer" of the type, so would turn `int*const` into a `int*`, but would leave a `int const&` or `int const*` untouched.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo up there for a short bit.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `decltype(*this)` is A ? You should investigate on that with an ugly `cout` debug  line.